# Regex for Removing Everything Before Certain Comma Position

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to remove and replace everything before the 13th comma in an array like so:

```
{1,1,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,20,4099,4241,706,706,714,714,817,824,824,824,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1},
```

to where it becomes:

```
{706,706,714,714,817,824,824,824,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1},
```

Reference: I'm using regex in `Notepad ++`.

I found this `regex` string to match everything after a certain comma to the end of the line:

```
,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*$
```

But how do I turn it around to start from the beginning?

I appreciate your time and help, thank you.

Comment: Look for `{\K(?:[^,}]*,){13}` and replace with an empty string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perhaps refrain from asking to be marked correct until after the OP has verbally confirmed this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen [I think OP already did that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882952/regex-for-removing-everything-before-certain-comma-position?noredirect=1#comment80714040_46883054)

Comment: You're right.  The acceptance rate has been abyssmal lately on SO.  I guess I need to start enjoying talking to myself.

Comment: @Steve, please consider accepting the answer that worked best for you and also consider upvoting any of the answers that were helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Whereas `$` matches the end of the subject string, `^` matches the beginning. So if you want to match up to and including the 13th comma:

```
^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,
```

Replace with "{".

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
{(?:[^,}]*,){13}
```

Replace with a mere `{`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJKJ8k/1). This version will work correctly even if you have `{...}` substrings spanning across lines and having fewer than 13 items in between.

**Details**

- `{` - a `{`
- `(?:[^,}]*,){13}` - 13 consecutive occurrences of

  - `[^,}]*` - 0+ chars other than `,` and `}` (the `}` is important to avoid overflowing from one `{...}` substring into another)
  - `,` - a comma

You may also use

```
{\K(?:[^,}]*,){13}
```

And replace with an empty string. See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJKJ8k/2). You do not need to replace with `{` because `\K` omits the first `{` from the match, and it is thus kept in the final text.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following find and replacement:

**Find:**

```
\{(?:[^,]*,){13}(.*)
```

**Replace:**

```
{$1
```

The above pattern could be slightly adjusted depending on what your expectations are for where this bracketed string might appear, edge cases you want to cover/avoid, etc.

## Demo